# Get row from inner select and by group

Tags: mysql, sql

Students table with 500,000- 1,000,000 rows

```
    |-----------------|------------------|------------------|
    |    id           |     name         |    ref_id        |
    |-----------------|------------------|------------------|
    |         1       |        test      |    NULL          |
    |-----------------|------------------|------------------|       
    |          2      |        test      |    1             |
    |-----------------|------------------|------------------|         
    |           3     |         test3    |    1             |
    |-----------------|------------------|------------------|
    |           4     |         test4    |    NULL          |
```

How do I query the following case:
return the rows that id in that row does not exist as any ref_id of the table and also only if the name appears more than 1

if in the table row id = 2 does not appear as any ref_id in another row ("2" does not appear as ref_id I should choose him and also the second condition is to took his name and check id the name is unique or not)

so in the above example, the rows to return is rows with id **2** . because it does not appear as a ref_if and also the name is more than 1.

row 3 is not good because the name test3 appears only 1

I tried:

```
SELECT st.id FROM students at
WHERE at.id NOT IN (SELECT stt.ref_id FROM students stt)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the row with an ID of 1 is the one to be returned? You state your condition is return rows where the ID is not in ref_id, yet that id appears twice in ref_id. That row does meet your 2nd condition - the name does appear twice, but fails the 1st condition.

Comment: @SloanThrasher . sorry, fixed the question

Comment: That row doesn't meet either of your conditions. The name only appears once, and there aren't any rows with a matching ref_id.

Comment: @SloanThrasher . why ?  row with id 2 . -> the id does not appears in any ref_id and akso the name "test" appears more than 1  so it meets my condition

Comment: for `id=2` ref_id is `1`, which is present. But, you said *does not exist in any ref_id*. It is contradicting

Comment: @Ravi . the id=2 does not appears as ref_id, anyone does not use the id=2 so I need to choose him and also check the second condition 
I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the list of `id`, which is not present in `ref_id`

```
SELECT st.id FROM students at
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM students stt where stt.ref_id=at.id)
```

Then get the list of `id` where `name` is repeated multiple times

```
SELECT id, name FROM student n1
inner join student n2 on n2.name=n1.name where n1.id <> n2.id
```

Now, join these two queries together

```
SELECT t1.id FROM
(SELECT st.id FROM students at
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM students stt where stt.ref_id=at.id)) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, name FROM student n1
inner join student n2 on n2.name=n1.name where n1.id <> n2.id
) t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: thanks I will try it. If I have another coulmn called name 2 and I need to check in pairs . Name 1 and name 2 together . How that it changed the query,?    I mean the name ="test", name2="guest" so it need to be the same in other rows

Comment: @Guz `on n2.name=n1.name` should change to `on n2.name=n1.name and n2.<another_col>=n1.<another_col>`

Comment: thanks ,the queries are working but together I got  Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: @Guz what do you mean by duplicate name `Id` ?

Comment: on other issue is that it takes too long  in 200,00 rows  (30-40) seconds

Comment: @Guz Yes, it will take time, since we are using many selection from same table. You could create index on `ref_id`, which could improve performance to some extent.

Comment: that not help a lot,  there is another way to do that ? maybe temp table or something ?

Comment: @Guz You are going to create unnecessary overhead for database for creating table storing data and truncating again. If you are going to run this query for one time then temp table option is good. Otherwise, this option is good AFAIK.

Comment: I going to  run it one time per day 
now it takes 8 second when I limit 200

Comment: @Guz why do you care about 30-40 sec. Even it takes 5 minutes. Then I'm fine with it. Since, it is performed once a day.

Comment: afraind it will makes problem to mysql when there are other request , it stuck the mysql 

what about first of all take only those who has name multiple time and only those id check if they are exist as ref_id 
is it possible ?

Comment: @Guz I don't know you application design and requirement. And, I have already gave you solution with segregation. Now, its your call how, what and when to execute depending on your requirement. All the best !!